# Виртуальные машины в качестве Dev и Staging — есть ли смысл?

Tags: виртуализация

Стоит выбор:

**А.** использовать в качестве девелоперского сервера отдельный старый железный сервер;

**Б.** поднять на новом мощном мастер-сервере виртуальные машины, в которых и тестировать код и куда пустить горе-девелоперов.

Плохая ли практика гонять на одном сервере и рабочие сервисы - MySQL Master, SVN, deployment скрипты, мониторинг; и еще запустить на нём же виртуальные машины с песочницами?

Мало опыта с виртуализацией - только на Маке винду запускаю иногда в окошке Parallels. Расскажите вкратце, если вообще целиться на вирт. машины, то надо уже всё по ним рассовывать, в т.ч. обернуть "рабочие" сервисы в одну из VM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Использовать виртуальные машины в качестве Dev и Staging очень удобно ввиду того что если что то случится с виртуальной машиной ее можно будет восстановить или откатиться из снапшота. В качестве системы виртуализации я бы порекомендовал Citrix xenserver. Xenserver есть в бесплатной редакции с некоторыми ограничениями. VirtualBox по производительности уступает xen. А для хранения виртуальных машин лучше использовать NAS.

Comment: спасибо! Как раз рассматриваю Xen сейчас как основной вариант.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы предпочел вариант **Б**...

Где-то читал, что не рекомендуется устанавливать виртуалки на контроллере домена... В остальном, вроде бы, ограничений особых нет. Если в принципе есть желание заморочиться с переносом ВСЕГО на виртуалки, то лучше делать это как можно раньше - раньше = меньше переносить = меньше гем0р@.

Управляет виртуалками [гипервизор](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D1%80). Соответственно, если переносить ВСЕ, то гипервизор или автономный или гибридный (если не ошибаюсь - сплошная проприетарщина). Такие ставятся на голое железо, уже под ними поднимаются, собственно, виртуальные машины. Туда и переносить.

Если ставить виртуалки в параллель с рабочим сервером - то достаточно поставить [VirtualBox](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/VirtualBox), установить ось на виртуальную машину - и вот он виртуальный сервер.

Я бы еще разнес все это дело по дисковому пространству: под рабочие сервисы - свои веники, под песочницы - свои. Впрочем, если бюджет позволяет активно использовать RAID...;)